# Copy Mysql data from RDS of one account to RDS of another account automatically

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services

I have My SQL-RDS on two AWS accounts. I need to copy data from one of them to the other one every day in order to have fresh data on the other RDS(The RDSs are private). What is the best way to do it?

Shall I create a script and use something like following commands:

```
backup: # mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

restore:# mysql -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] < dumpfilename.sql
```

or shall I copy data from RDS to a S3-bucket everyday and from S3-bucket to another RDS-AWSaccount? Like:

1. create S3-bucket in account1 and copy mysqldump data into it.
2. create S3-bucket in account2
3. copy database from S3-bucket-account1 to S3-bucket-account2
4. import database from S3-bucket-account2 to RDS-account2
5. use cronjob to run it everyday

or is there any other way?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1.Your can use snapshots for this.
Take snapshot of the current RDS.
Share the snapshot privately to another account,
Then restore the snapshot.

2.use aws DMS service.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42552099/6885516

Comment: Thanks for the reply. well I can not use the first option because I don't want to create new RDS every time, I just want to import database to an existent RDS server. But I will check out the AWS-DMZ.